# Trying to loop through images and add them to array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, loops

I'm trying to loop through my mutable array and add image objects 3-81. Heres my code. Can someone tell me why its not working?

```
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.imageData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.gif"],       [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.gif"],  nil];

        for (int i = 3; i <= 81; i++) {
            NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%i", i];
            [self.imageData addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: How **exactly** it is not working?

Comment: You should really be checking that the image exists before adding it to the array. If the image fails to load you'll be adding nil to an array which will throw an exception.

Comment: ur right. I'm new to programming. thanks for the tip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding images named "image1.gif" and "image2.gif". However, in your loop you are adding images named "image3", "image4", "image5", etc. The missing ".gif" is likely the problem.

```
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%i.gif", i];
```